# Salesforce Social Studio not picking up mentions from Facebook and Instagram

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-studio

I've been setting up topic profiles in Social Studio Analyse. Thing is, it doesnt seem to pick up mentions from Facebook and Instagram. The largest social network mentions that i see comes from Twitter. Is there a reason to this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the missing post a comment made on a post which is an @mention by a third party of the managed Facebook social account? These types of posts are not made directly on the client's Facebook Page, and therefore we are unable to access further content resulting from the post (ie comment/replies). As it does not "belong to the client's page," we do not have permissions to crawl that user's page. This is a Permissions/API limitation of this type of post.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313275&type=1